# How to set Python libraries in .pro file of Qt

Tags: pyqt

can anyone  tell me which libraries will be added in the following line: 
 "LIBS += -L$(PYLIB) -lutil -lpython2.6"

After reading some online articles and tutorials, it seems util.lib and python2.6.lib  should  be added in python library, but I did not find these two libraries anywhere. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is a pyqt question? What is your specific use-case that you have a pyqt app, using a .pro ?

Answer (score 0):

the -L option adds directories to be searched for -l statements.
So resolve PYLIB, which should stand atop of the Makefile. Then you might find the libraries.

But if you have problems with linking, because the libraries are not to be found, there might be a problem with the package you downloaded or something. :)

I would help more, but the question lacks some contextual information.